# webflo and behat issue preventing patch via composer

Tags: composer

I am attempting to install a patch for the [smtp](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module on a Drupal 8.8.4 vagrant dev instance.

Trying to do so fails with the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - webflo/drupal-core-require-dev 8.8.4 requires behat/mink 1.7.x-dev -> no matching package found.
    - webflo/drupal-core-require-dev 8.8.4 requires behat/mink 1.7.x-dev -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for webflo/drupal-core-require-dev 8.8.4 -> satisfiable by webflo/drupal-core-require-dev[8.8.4].
```

I don't have behat/mink required at all. This error seems completely unconnected to smtp and I have never seen it before on any other updates.

I understand behat/mink 1.7 doesn't exist but there is a 1.8 version. However, when I try to install it I get the following:

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for webflo/drupal-core-require-dev (locked at 8.8.4, required as ^8.6.0) -> satisfiable by webflo/drupal-core-require-dev[8.8.4].
    - Can only install one of: behat/mink[1.7.x-dev, 1.8.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: behat/mink[1.8.x-dev, 1.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: behat/mink[1.7.x-dev, 1.8.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: install behat/mink 1.7.x-dev
    - Installation request for behat/mink 1.8.x-dev -> satisfiable by behat/mink[1.8.x-dev].
```

I feel like I have tried every possible version of 1.8: 1.8, 1.8.0, 1.8.x-dev. Regardless off what version I ask for composer tries to install 1.7 every time and will not allow behat/mink to install.

How can I fix this? Do I even need `webflo/drupal-core-require-dev`? I am still not completely sure what it does.

Comment: You don't need the webflo package with >=8.8, you would use `drupal/core-dev` instead. See [the upgrade guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer#migrate-webflo-drupal-core-strict-to-core-recommended) for more info; the section linked to is worth reading for context, but it's the next section which talks about the dev package specifically

Comment: That update process feels very hacky.